# How to get entries from SQL that only appear in certain value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find entries in my SQL table that always and only appear in a certain value.

For example:

```
DeviceID    Transmission
--------    ------------
000329      Inventory
000980      Inventory
004406      Starting
000980      Stopping
000329      Inventory
004406      Inventory
```

Now I need to find all DeviceIDs that only have Inventory Transmissions and never Starting or Stopping. In this case 000329.

Comment: NOT starting or stopping.........OR...... = Transmissions.... which one? theres a difference

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This is (potentially) problematic!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all `Transmission = 'Inventory'` ids and filter out those exist in `Transmission in('Starting', 'Stopping')`:

```
select distinct(DeviceID) from YourTable
WHERE Transmission = 'Inventory'
and DeviceID not in
( select distinct(DeviceID) from YourTable
  WHERE Transmission in('Starting', 'Stopping')
);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81896/12

Comment: your answer is very similar to the one posted by [jarlh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30997944/4436237)

Comment: @ughai The most difference is that I use `distinct` to avoid duplication. jarlh's answer use join `t1.DeviceID = t2.DeviceID` within his `not exists` clause, while mine is not.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function so the parens accomplish nothing. In fact you really don't need it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude DeviceID's that also have Starting or Stopping.

```
select DeviceID
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.DeviceID = t2.DeviceID
                    and t2.Transmission in ('Starting','Stopping'))
  and t1.Transmission = 'Inventory'
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, However `group by` with conditional `having` would be faster.

Comment: Even if both DeviceID and Transmission are indexed?

Comment: In case of `NOT EXISTS` the table would be looked up twice. With `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, it would happen only once.

Comment: `and t1.Transmission = 'Inventory'` this condition also not needed for op

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande, just wanted to make sure "only have Inventory Transmissions and never Starting or Stopping". (Perhaps there are other values in the table not shown in the sample data...)

Comment: @jarlh in that case it will need most ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` like this

**Query**

```
SELECT DeviceID
FROM DevicesTable
GROUP BY DeviceID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Transmission = 'Inventory' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN Transmission <> 'Inventory' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b470/1)**

**OUTPUT**

```
DeviceID
000329
```

If you only want to check against `Transmission in ('Starting','Stopping')`, you can add  `Transmission IN ('Starting','Stopping')` instead of `Transmission <> 'Inventory'` in the second conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you have only these three states with these names (**'Inventory', 'Starting', 'Stopping'**) you could use:

```
select deviceID from table1 
group by deviceID 
having max(transmission)='Inventory'
```

Using **max** here is valid because **'Starting', 'Stopping'** are alphabetically orderd after **'Inventory'**.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81896/8

The result is the correct **000329**.

Comment: Hmm, witty, but limited. And potentially disastrous!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, probably because I have more transmission entries that come before Inventory in alphabetical order?

Comment: @strawberry: ;) you are right, but the question was limited regarding transmission names.

Comment: @tom: what is your complete transmission list or do you have numeric ids for this transmission names?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select *
from tablename 
where DeviceID not in 
(select DeviceID from tablename 
where Transmission in('Starting','Stopping'))
and Transmission='Inventory';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
-- You didn't give a name for your table
SELECT DeviceID from YourTable WHERE Transmission = 'Inventory'
```

Comment: You forgot the "never Starting or Stopping" part.

Comment: @jarlh But if it is 'Inventory' it can't be any other thing (starting or stopping) included

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want (and if you have more `Transmission` values)

```
SELECT DeviceID, Transmission
FROM yourtable
WHERE Transmission NOT IN ('Starting', 'Stopping')
```

Or

```
SELECT DeviceID, Transmission
FROM yourtable
WHERE Transmission = 'Inventory'
```